# Ошибка в конструктуре класса c++

Tags: c++, ооп, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct Node {
    int val, key, sz;
    Node * left,  * right;
    Node(int value): val(value), key(rand()), sz(1), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
};
typedef Node * Pnode;
int size(Pnode root) {
    if (!root) {
        return 0;
    }
    return root->sz;
}
void update(Pnode & root) {
    if(root)
        root->sz = size(root->left) + size(root->right) + 1;
}
void merge(Pnode & t, Pnode l, Pnode r) {
    if (!l || !r)
        t = l ? l : r;
    else if (l->key > r->key)
        merge(l->right, l->right, r), t = l;
    else
        merge(r->left, l, r->left), t = r;
    update(t);
}

void split(Pnode t, Pnode & l, Pnode & r, int key, int add = 0) {
    if (!t)
        return void(l = r = 0);
    int cur_key = add + size(t->left); // вычисляем неявный ключ
    if (key <= cur_key)
        split(t->left, l, t->left, key, add), r = t;
    else
        split(t->right, t->right, r, key, add + 1 + size(t->left)), l = t;
    update(t);
}
void push(Pnode & root, int k) {
    Pnode a(k);
    merge(root, root, a);
}
int main()
{
    int n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    Pnode g(1);
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        push(g, i);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        push(g, i);
    }

}
```

Comment: ошибка в передаче цифры 1 в констуктор

Comment: Pnode у вас указатель на Node. В выражении типа `Pnode g(1)` вы пытаетесь инициализировать указатель значением 1. У вас же нет `Node`, его надо создать - например, `Pnode g = new Node(1);`